# ParametricNDSolve

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

want to solve this equation and get 2 dimensional plot with N2 on X-axis and `theta(1)` on the Y-axis with `x from 0 to 1` and `N2 varies from 0 to 5`
`theta''[x] + theta'[x] - 
   (N2)^2*theta[x] +theta[x]^3 == 0, theta'[1] == 1, 
 theta[0] == 0`
please help

Comment: What have you tried so far? Generally, you get better (and more) answers if you show your attempts. Even if they're not working, this shows where exactly you're stuck.

Comment: I am new in Mathematica and try to learn it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "11.3.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (March 7, 2018)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

The differential equation can be solved analytically with [`DSolve`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/DSolve.html)

```
eqns = {theta''[x] + theta'[x] - Exp[-x]*N2^2*theta[x] == 0, 
   theta'[1] == -1/4, theta[0] == 1};

sol = DSolve[eqns, theta, x][[1]];
```

Verifying that `sol` satisfies `eqns`

```
And @@ (eqns /. sol // FullSimplify)

(* True *)

theta[x_, N2_] = (theta /. sol)[x] // FullSimplify

(* (Sqrt[E^-x]
     BesselK[1, 
     2 Sqrt[E^-x] N2] (4 Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[1, N2^2/E] - 
      E Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2, N2^2]) + 
   E^-x (4 N2 BesselK[0, (2 N2)/Sqrt[E]] + 
      E BesselK[1, 2 N2]) Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[2, 
     E^-x N2^2])/(4 (BesselI[1, 2 N2] BesselK[0, (2 N2)/Sqrt[E]] + 
     BesselK[1, 2 N2] Hypergeometric0F1Regularized[1, N2^2/E])) *)

Plot[theta[1, N2], {N2, 0, 5},
 Frame -> True,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"N2", "theta[1]"})]
```

[image]

```
NMinimize[{theta[1, N2], N2 > 0}, N2]

(* {-0.0588834, {N2 -> 5.74844}} *)

Limit[theta[1, N2], N2 -> Infinity]

(* 0 *)

Plot[theta[1, N2], {N2, 0, 25},
 Frame -> True,
 PlotRange -> All,
 FrameLabel -> (Style[#, 14, Bold] & /@ {"N2", "theta[1]"})]
```

[image]

Comment: thanks Bob Hanlon, now if i expend my problem then what to do? 'eqns = {theta''[x] + theta'[x] - Exp[-x]*N2^2*theta[x] +theta[x]^3== 0, 
   theta'[1] == -1/4, theta[0] == 1}'

Comment: Comments are not the appropriate place to ask different questions.